# google API redirect_url fail after authentication Allow Access

Tags: ios, google-api

Hi everyone this is the first time I post question, might make some mistakes. 
So I want to create an iOS app that could let user manage youtube stuff, which means I need to use the oAuth2.0 google API for authentication if users need to.

The third party code for oAuth2 I was using is  OAuth2Client. After several 
hours I got to the point that I could get to the authentication page for google. But after clicking Allow Access or Deny, the page stuck there. I just wonder if it was meant to be like that or there's something wrong with my code.

Here's my code for oAuth2

```
+ (void)initialize;
{
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]  setClientID:@"243181519584.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                                         secret:@"9b_K3C-kYp791Syga5K47cFS"
                                          scope:[NSSet setWithObject:@""]
                               authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                                       tokenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                                    redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]
                                 forAccountType:@"NBAvideo"];

}


//send request for logging in
[[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] requestAccessToAccountWithType:@"NBAvideo"];


//add observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:
 NXOAuth2AccountStoreAccountsDidChangeNotification     object:[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification){
                                                  NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                  }];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NXOAuth2AccountStoreDidFailToRequestAccessNotification
                                                  object:[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification){
                                                  NSError *error = [aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:NXOAuth2AccountStoreErrorKey];
                                                  NSLog(@"Failure !");
                                              }];
```

After I click Allow Access or Deny, the page url is my redirect_url + code 
= ........,I wonder how I could get that, because I application server doesn't hear anything as I add observer to notification center. As the google api center gave me the redirect url when I register the product, I used the 'localhost' in my code, just wonder if that's right..Anyone could help~, I've looking for a solution all day.

Thank you!